# Converting string with tags in it to BeautifulSoup tag object

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to save some < li > tags that I encounter while scraping a website, so that I can come back to them and process them later if I need more information.

I tried saving them to a csv file, while inside a DataFrame, but whenever I load the DataFrame back up, I find that the tags I saved got converted to strings. I can't find a way to convert them back into **< class 'bs4.element.Tag' >** objects. I'd like to be able to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Typically, questions don't get answers unless we can see your code attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, given a string with HTML tags, you can just convert it to `bs4.element.Tag` by doing:

```
htmlStr = '<li>Coffee</li>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlStr, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.find_all('li')
```

So, given that you have a dataframe like this:

```
              tags
0  <li>Coffee</li>
1     <li>Tea</li>
2   <li>Water</li>
```

You can create a function to convert the HTML like string to `bs4.element.Tag`:

```
def str_to_bs4(x):
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')
    html_tags = html_soup.find_all('li')
    return html_tags
```

Now use the `lambda` function to pass string from each row and convert them back by calling the function:

```
df['tags_bs4'] = df['tags'].apply(lambda x: str_to_bs4(x))
```

Output:

```
              tags    tags_bs4
0  <li>Coffee</li>  [[Coffee]]
1     <li>Tea</li>     [[Tea]]
2   <li>Water</li>   [[Water]]
```